# I have a cave that covers 270°, how can the camera cover that area

Tags: camera

i have a CAVE setup that covers 270degree around me, how can i adjust the camera to let me see the full 270degree in fullscreen when i walk around in the game engine.

Comment: Just a note, the game engine has officially been removed from the next version of Blender. I think though you just need to change your camera settings, isn't it like a normal scene as far as the camera is concerned?

Comment: The thing im trying to figure out is, I attached a camera to an object that I can move around. I want that camera to be able to see the surrounding in 270°, so that when I load it into my 3x projector cave I can move around and look left and right without moving the camera

Comment: What exactly has been the issue? This seems pretty straightforward to me. Just normal camera properties right?

Comment: Then I havent found the right settings for it, when i press P in the Blender game nothing achieved that view for me so far. What properties do i have to change to make that 270° view happen?

Comment: Go to the camera's settings . . . a quick google search should teach you everything you need to know. Feel free to ask about specific issues, generic things like this don't really help anyone. Try and learn about a topic yourself first before asking here, it will save everyone a lot of time. What you want to do may or may not be possible, what isn't possible is giving you a helpful answer right now. We just need to have a specific question with a detailed description of what you tried.